# How to perform two action while click a button in HTML with js?

Tags: javascript, html

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
           <body>
               <h2>DATE&TIME</h2>
               <button type="button" 
               onclick="document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML = Date()">
               View Date</button>
                <p id="sun"></p>
              <button type="button"
              onclick="document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML = ' 
              '";"document.getElementById('sun1').innerHTML = 'Press to 
              View'";>Clear</button>
                 <p id="sun1"></p>
            </body>                                         
        </html>
```

I want to perform two action while button is clicked. My above code was not work. Please give solution.

Comment: in the onclick, call a (local function) which itself calls two actions.

Comment: Java is not javascript

Comment: the semicolon is wrong. Place it inside the value of ``onclick``, not afterwards.

Comment: Have a look at some basics about JavaScript as it is hard to solve a problem if the fundamentals are not there. Something like: [**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript)

Comment: @Sunderesan Bro if you got your answer please accept the right answer since no one is sitting idle in this world. All is working hard and they help others to get satisfaction from their hard work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than 1 lines go separate user define function using script tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <script>
       function clearbtn(){
              document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML ='';
              document.getElementById('sun1').innerHTML = 'Press to View';
       }
       function dateTime(){
          document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML = Date();
          document.getElementById('sun1').innerHTML = '';
       }
       </script>
       </head>
           <body>
               <h2>DATE&TIME</h2>
               <button type="button" onclick="dateTime()">View Date</button>
               <p id="sun"></p>
               <button type="button" onclick="clearbtn()">Clear</button>
               <p id="sun1"></p>
            </body>                                         
        </html>
```

Comment: thanks its works, but without function is possible or not?

Comment: You Can do like this `<button type="button" onclick="(function(){
    document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML = Date();
          document.getElementById('sun1').innerHTML = '';
})();">View Date</button>
<p id="sun"></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Just call a local javascript function

```
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction();">Clear</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('sun1').innerHTML = 'Press to View';
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, avoid inline javascript !
- Gives your button an unique ID

  `<button type="button" id="datebutt">View Date</button>`

  `<p id="sun"></p>`

  `<button type="button" id="clearbutt">Clear</button>`

  `<p id="sun1"></p>`
- Then in your script you can do

  `<script>`

  `document.getElementById("datebutt").addEventListener("click",function(){`

  ```
  document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML = Date()`
  ```

  `},false);`

  `document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click",function(){`

  ```
  document.getElementById('sun').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('sun1').innerHTML = 'Press to View';
  ```

  `},false);`

  `</script>`

Comment: Sorry, code editing issues in Stack Overflow, try to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the best solution for this

In js page :-

```
function do(){
 // your code here
}
function do_more(){
 // your code here
}
```

In Html page :-

```
<button onclick='do();do_more();'>Button</button>
```